# The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured error for self referencing

Tags: entity-framework

So I have this entity:

```
public class Transaction {

public Guid Id {get;set;}
public virtual Transaction Reference {get;set;}
public virtual Transaction Original {get;set;}

}
```

`Reference` and `Original` both serve their own business rules purpose, and they are both not required. I've had `Original` there for quite a while and it works fine, I recently added `Reference` and I'm getting `The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.`

I can't figure out how to set up my Fluent Configuration. I currently don't have anything in place for `Original`, so I'm not sure if my errors are stemming from my newest addition or its now breaking what existed. Here is the full error:

Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Core.Transaction' and 'Core.Transaction'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.